# How to make python read all files in directory for a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a collection of 20 text files in a folder that I am trying to create a dictionary for and output the dictionary to a text file.

I created a code that works for a single file in the directory by inputting a filename.  However it doesn't let me input multiple text files at once, and if I run each one individually they just overwrite each other.  I tried converting the file input to using import os and read from my cwd, but I'm running into errors with variables and I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
fname = input ('Enter File: ')
hand = open(fname)

di = dict()
for lin in hand:
    lin = lin.rstrip()
    wds = lin.split()
    for w in wds:


        di[w] = di.get(w,0) + 1

print(di)


largest = -1
theword = None
for k,v in di.items() : 
    if v > largest : 
        largest = v
        theword = k

print(theword,largest)

f = open("output.txt", "w")
f.write(str(di))
f.close()
```

I tried adding

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    fname = ('*.txt')
    hand = open(fname)
```

To the top, but I'm erroring out as it's not recognizing what I thought would be a wildcard to assign fname as the file it is reading.

Comment: It seems you are counting words in files and calculating their frequencies. That's a perfect case use for [```collections.Counter```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each and every .txt file inside your directory and print or store the content of those text files in a dictionary or variable.

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
         name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
         if '.txt' in file_extension:
                hand = open(filename)
                for line in hand:
                    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3.4 or higher, your code can be very simplified by using [`pathlib.Path()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
dir = Path('dir')
out_file = Path('output.txt')

for file in dir.glob('*.txt'):
    with file.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for l in f:
            counter.update(l.strip().split())

counter.most_common(10)

with out_file.open('w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(counter)
```

If you are on Python 3.5 or higher, that code can be even more simple:

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
dir = Path('dir')
out_file = Path('output.txt')

for file in dir.glob('*.txt'):
    counter.update(file.read_text(encoding='utf-8').split())

counter.most_common(10)
out_file.write_text(counter, encoding='utf-8')
```

And here is as sample output:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> file = Path('t.txt')
>>> file.is_file()
True
>>> with file.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
...     for l in f:
...             counter.update(l.strip().split())
... 
>>> counter.most_common(5)
[('is', 10), ('better', 8), ('than', 8), ('to', 5), ('the', 5)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use wildcards, you need the `glob` module.  But in your case it sounds like you just want all files in one directory, so:

```
for filename in os.listdir('.'): # . is cwd
    hand = open(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

# a list of all txt file in the current dir
files = glob.glob("*.txt")

# the dictionary that will hold the file names (key) and content (value)
dic = {}
# loop to opend files
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as read:
        # the key will hold the name the value the content
        dic[file] = read.read()
        # For each file we will append the name and the content in output.txt
        with open("output.txt", "a", encoding = 'utf-8') as output:
            output.write(dic[file] + "\n" + read.read() + "\n\n")
```